# Difference between Was and Were- "It was these months towards which the whole year moved."

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, inversion, subjects

> It ***was*** these months towards which the whole year moved.

In this sentence why did the writer not use **were** in place of ***was***?

Since this is an inversion sentence as "it" is used, shouldn't the verb be according to the subject: "these months"?

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, the subject is not *these months*, the subject is *it*, and *it* is always singular.

We call this an [anticipatory it or dummy it](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/it).  It might help to think of it this way:
 - The whole year moved towards something.
 - What was that thing?
 - **It was these months** (towards which the whole year moved).